# mouseover to display appropriated div for link

Tags: jquery, html, hidden

I need to have each div link  make the appropriate div text to appear at the bottom of the page. I have it partially set up but I wanted to know if there was a better way to steam line this code.

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $('#item1').hover(
        function () {
            $('#Tile1').fadeIn( 'fast' );
        }, 
        function () {
            $('#Tile1').fadeOut( 'fast' );
        });
    });

    $(function () {
        $('#item2').hover(
        function () {
            $('#Tile2').fadeIn( 'fast' );
        },
        function () {
            $('#Tile2').fadeOut( 'fast' );
        });
    });
</script>
 <div class="four columns alpha">
     <a href="solutions/mobile.php" id="item1">
     <img src="images/1.png" alt="" class="tiles" /></a>
 </div>
 <div id="Tile1" class=" sixteen columns" style="display: none;">
     <h3 class="center">GIS / Mapping</h3>
     <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas id justo 
     </p>
</div>
```

The Divs are not nested because I want the text to always appear at the bottom of the page no matter which link you hover over.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `$(function(){ ... }` doesn't need to be repeated for each function, and you can use functions such as `fadeToggle()` to reduce the amount of code:

```
$(function () {
    $("div[id^='item']").hover(function(){
        var selector = '#Tile' + $(this).attr('id').replace('item', '');
        $(selector).fadeToggle('fast');
    });
});
```

This assumes your IDs are always in the format: `item(N)` maps to `Title(N)`.

The second line selects all elements where the ID begins with `item` and the line that follows selects the ID after `item` and uses it to select the appropriate `<div>`.

Comment: This worked beautifully! One may I ask you to go one step further with me? I noticed that once the animation has begun it won't stop until competed *ex. If I spam hover over a few items the toggle will loop until each mouseover command is complete. It sounds nit-picky I know but if you happen to know how to solve it I would appreciate it.

Comment: Without seeing your exact implementation you could use `$(selector).stop().fadeToggle('fast')` to stop current animations.

Comment: Here's a quick and dirty JsFiddle link if you would like to take a look. http://jsfiddle.net/wVKvL/ if you rapidly rollover the links the div toggle keeps going and going.

Comment: Indeed, so adding the `stop()` function as I mentioned prevents duplicate animations be queued up on the same element.

Comment: Once I added the '$(selector).stop().fadeToggle('fast')' The animation only seems to work if I quickly flash over the links. I may be just calling the functionality incorrectly. [JsFiddleUpdated](http://jsfiddle.net/kayhart/GWKJr/7/)

Comment: You are a gentleman and a scholar - Thank you again. That was what I needed.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand it correctly. you want to show the `<div>` content next to `<a>` div.  you can try.

```
$(function () {
    $('[id^=item]').hover(function(){
        $(this).parent().next().fadeToggle();
    });
});
```